# How to configure the GitHub default issue filter parameters?

Tags: github, github-issues

When searching for GitHub issues a default search filter (`is:pr is:open`) is applied. See [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/using-search-to-filter-issues-and-pull-requests) and [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/filtering-issues-and-pull-requests) documentation pages of GitHub.

How can I configure an alternative default filter for this search?

The reason behind this is, that we want to hide our [renovate bot](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) PRs for normal operations.

Comment: I agree that this is annoying. If you’d like, you can upvote my feature request to have a separate UI for not PRs. https://github.com/community/community/discussions/4520

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any way to change the default filter. However, if someone is looking for a way to filter out those PR that do *not* include involving renovatebot, simply add `NOT renovate-bot` to your search query.

Comment: The filter that works for me is `-author:app/renovate`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do this is save a bookmark/favorite:

https://github.com/YourAccount/Repo/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc+-label%3Abacklog++-label%3Abug

Filter:

is:issue is:open sort:updated-desc -label:backlog  -label:bug